# Python circular dependency with the inclusion of member functions

Tags: python, circular-dependency

The issue here arises when I try and incorporate an existing function into a class as a member function. I have a setup similar to this:

Classes:

```
base(object)
    primitive(base)
        square(primitive)
        union(primitive)
```

I have a function called `union` that the user calls that returns a `union` primitive object.

```
obj1 = square()
obj2 = square()
obj3 = union(obj1, obj2) #this is the union function which returns a union primitive
```

I want the user to also be able to do this

```
obj3 = obj1.union(obj2)
```

This is where the issue arises. The `primitive` class needs to import the `union` function, which in turn imports the `union` class, which in turn imports the `primitive` class, and I run into a circular dependency error. Is there a smart way to refactor the code or to alter the import statements to allow this to work?

EDIT:

For some clarity this is how the code is structued:

**operations/union.py** (the function)

```
from objects import union as _union #the union class
def union(obj1, obj2): #the union function
    #CODE
    return _union(args)
```

**objects/union.py** (the class)

```
from objects import primitive
class union(primitive):
    #CODE
```

**objects/primitive.py**

```
from operations import union #the function
class primitive(base):
    #CODE
    def union(self, obj2):
        return union(self, obj2)
```

There is a class called `union`, which is an object that contains the information on the unioned input objects. The user does not interact with this. Then there is the `union` function that the user can call, which returns a `union` object. I want the `primitive` class to contain a member function, called `union`, that uses the `union` function I have already written. The problem is that the `union` function returns a `union` object that inherits from the `primitive` class. This causes a circular dependency issue. I can remove the `union` member function but then the user can't do this

```
obj3 = obj1.union(obj2)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Your diagrams do not make sense to me. Is Union a class or a function? What *exactly* is going on? In any case, just out these things in the same module a d your circular dependency can be solved.

Comment: Let me know if that edit clears things up

Comment: Why don't you just put all the classes in the same module? Or put `union` the class and `union` the function in the same module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've caused a lot of trouble for yourself by having `primitive` and `square` defined in separate modules/files. If you defined them in the same module, I doubt you'd have any trouble. For example, the following works fine:

```
class Primitive:
    pass

class Square(Primitive):
    def union(self, other):
        return Union(self, other)

class Union(Primitive):
    def __init__(self, *members):
        self.members = members

obj1 = Square()
obj2 = Square()
obj3 = obj1.union(obj2)

print(type(obj3))
print(obj3.members)
```

If you insist on putting your classes in different files, though, you can do something like this:

```
primitive.py:

    class Primitive:
        pass

square.py:

    from .primitive import Primitive

    class Square(Primitive):
        def union(self, other):
            from .union import Union
            return Union(self, other)

union.py:

    from .primitive import Primitive

    class Union(Primitive):
        def __init__(self, *members):
            self.members = members

test.py:

    from .square import Square

    obj1 = Square()
    obj2 = Square()
    obj3 = obj1.union(obj2)

    print(type(obj3))
    print(obj3.members)
```

The key point is moving the `from .union import Union` statement inside the `union()` method, where it won't be invoked until it's needed.

Here's a [good resource](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/) on Python circular imports.

Comment: The main reason they aren't all in the same file is that there are several primitives and each has a good deal of code. Is it bad form to have 1000+ line files?

Comment: @Chris. Yes it is. And it's bad form to import in a function. Just stick the import at the end.

Comment: @ChrisUchytil Either way is fine. When I write a recursive descent parser (which naturally have a lot of cyclic dependencies) I put everything in one long file to avoid this exact problem. Other people like to split them out by files so their projects are easier to navigate. Programmers coming from Java tend to put each class in a separate file, which is neither necessary or helpful in Python. Good Python code bases like scikit-learn or Django tend to have a handful of closely related classes in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't rely on anything from an import at the module level, you can place the import at the end of the file. In case of `union`, `Primitive` is required to define a class in module scope, so keep `union.py` as-is:

```
from objects.primitive import Primitive
class Union(Primitive):
    @classmethod
    def union(cls, a, b):
        return Union(a, b)
```

But `primitive` only requires `Union` in one method, not to create anything in module scope, so all you need is for the imported module to exist by the time the method is called. That means you can do this:

```
class Primitive(Base):
    #CODE
    def union(self, obj2):
        return union.Union.union(self, obj2)

from objects import union
```

The reason you need to put the import at the end is to ensure that it works no matter which module gets imported first. If you import `objects.union`, it will correctly import `objects.primitive` before it gets to the module body. If you import `objects.primitive` first, it will attempt to import `objects.union`, which requires the `Primitive` class to already exist. Hence the import after the class body.

I recommend making `union` a `@classmethod` of `Union` so that you can use it properly as an alternate constructor. Also, using the Python convention of writing class names in CamelCase makes the naming much less confusing.